# How to make SmartGWT TreeGrid reparent selectively allowed depending on nodes

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, treegrid

I have the following data in a SmartGWT TreeGrid object.

```
Home
 |-Room 1
 |-Room 2
    |-Table
    |-Chair
```

Reparenting is allowed by calling `treeGrid.setCanReparentNodes(true);`

I want to allow selectiv reparenting only: for example, it should be possible to move (drag&drop) the Table to Room 1, but it should not be possible to move the Room 1 into Room2 or the Chair into Home.

How can I selectively allow reparenting depending on the node type (or a node's attribute)?